# Как сделать инвентарь через json python?

Tags: python, json, discord

День вожусь с показом инвентаря в дискорд боте. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы вывелся предмет и его число. Например:

```
test x1
test1 x1
test2 x4
```

Но получается так:

```
[['test'], ['test1'], ['test2']] x[1, 1, 4]
```

Как сделать то, что мне нужно?

```
@bot.command(aliases=["inv", "инвентарь"])
async def inventory(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.author
    with open(f"{member.id}.json", "r") as write_file:
        data = json.load(write_file)
    invItem = data["item"]
    invAmount = data["amount"]

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Инвентарь {member}", description=f"Инвентарь:\n{invItem} x{invAmount}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Так расскажите хотябы из чего собирать строку, а лучше покажие

Comment: @Namerek Не сильно понял, что вы хотите

Comment: Лично я, хочу кофе и круассан.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
invItem, invAmount = [['test'], ['test1'], ['test2']], [1, 1, 4]
# я вот это имел ввиду ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# потому, что этот ответ верен для набора данных вот в таком формате
# Кроме того если количество элементов в списках invItem и invAmount будет разным, 
# то лучше использовать zip_longest
items_str = '\n'.join(f'{ii} x{ia}' for (ii,), ia in zip(invItem, invAmount))
print(items_str)
```

---

```
test x1
test1 x1
test2 x4
```